# I have a two Controllers, A and B. How can I use a method in B from A?

Tags: laravel

I have a two Controllers, A and B. How can I use a method in B from A? For example:

```
class A extends BaseController {
    public function a() {

    }
}
```

...and in another file...

```
class B extends BaseController {
    public function b() {

    }

    public function c() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How can I use function c() from function a()?

Comment: By creating an instance of class A then calling it's method.

Comment: For static method calls you just need to do `A::a();` and non-static calls require making an instance `$myA = new A(...);` then calling the method like: `$myA->a();`.

Comment: The question here would be, why would you want to do that? If there is logic in a method from controller A which you want to reuse, you should create a service/library which holds that logic anyway. Then you can use that logic inside every other controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//AController.blade.php

class A extends BaseController {

   private $b;    

   public function __construct(B) {
      $this->b = new B();
   }

    public function a() {
       $this->b->c();
    }
}

//BController.blade.php

class B extends BaseController {
    public function b() {

    }

    public function c() {
      echo('Im method from controller B');
    }
}
```